# Minimizing trace of matrix inverse is an SDP?

Tags: convex-optimization, inverse, trace, semidefinite-programming, linear-matrix-inequality

I'm reading through [this paper](https://hal.inria.fr/hal-00940321/document) and on page 8 (PDF page 9), Step 2 in Algorithm 1 reads
$$
W \leftarrow  \text{argmin} \{\text{tr}(WQW^T) + \alpha\, \text{tr}(Q^{−1}): Q \succeq \epsilon\, I_n , Q_{\text{off}} \leq 0, Q \,\mathbb{1}_n = \epsilon\, \mathbb{1}_n \}
$$
where $Q$ is symmetric and $W$ is a $d\times n$ matrix. The following paragraphs claim this is an SDP, "since 
$\text{tr}(Q^{-1})\leq\beta$ can be rewritten as 
$$
\text{tr}(R)\leq\beta, \qquad
\begin{bmatrix}R & I_n \\ I_n & Q\end{bmatrix} \succeq 0."
$$
How are the two conditions equivalent? More importantly, how would this be implemented in an SDP solver like CVX?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You introduce a new variable $R$ for which it holds $R \succeq Q^{-1}$ from which you know  $\text{tr}(R) \geq \text{tr}(Q^{-1})$. If you now add a cost in the objective of $\text{tr}(R)$, at optimality it would be optimal to select $R=Q^{-1}$ (otherwise you could decrease the objective by making $R$ smaller). The inequality  $R \succeq Q^{-1}$ is then converted to an LMI using a Schur complement.

The reformulation introducing yet another variable $\beta$ to upper bound $\text{tr}(R)$ is just silly and adds nothing. Simply use $\text{tr}(R)$ in the objective.

The model is then an absolutely bog standard LMI and would be immediately implemented in CVX or YALMIP or your language of choice.

Comment: To fill in the details re: Schur complement a little: Since $Q\succeq \epsilon I_n\succ 0$, the Schur complement condition tells us that $X=\begin{bmatrix}R & I_n \\ I_n & Q\end{bmatrix} \succeq 0$ if and only if $X/Q=R-Q^{-1}\succeq 0$ i.e. $R\succeq Q^{-1}$.